# Grouping of bash conditionals

Tags: bash

I have the following `bash` condition test which I need to change.

```
if (( exec_rc == 1 )) && [ -z "$keymap_actm" ] && [ -n "$modmap_actm" ]; then
```

`(( exec_rc == 1 ))` must always be true.

But if either one of the two `[ -z "$keymap_actm" ]` or `[ -n "$modmap_actm" ]` is true, I want to execute the body of the condition.

What is a readable way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping is done with parentheses, in a similar way as with arithmetic.

You could do (not recommended):

```
if (( exec_rc == 1 )) && ( [ -z "$keymap_actm" ] || [ -n "$modmap_actm" ] ); then
```

But, in the example above, the parentheses are creating a sub-shell. It works, but better avoid the subshell using shell braces:

```
if (( exec_rc == 1 )) && { [ -z "$keymap_actm" ] || [ -n "$modmap_actm" ] ; }; then
```

Or you could use a `[[` to group (do not use a `[`) :

```
if (( exec_rc == 1 )) && [[ -z "$keymap_actm" || -n "$modmap_actm" ]]; then
```

Or (recommended syntax):

```
if [[ exec_rc -eq 1 && ( -z "$keymap_actm" || -n "$modmap_actm" ) ]]; then
```

Note that the `[[` syntax will work on all versions of bash and most of Ksh or zsh, but not in Bourne `sh`.

Comment: Don't you need `$exec_rc -eq 1` actually?

Comment: Yes, you do if the variable is not inside an arithmetic context. The operator `-eq` is the one converting both sides of the expression to arithmetic. Of course, you can replace the whole `$exec_rc -eq 1` with `((exec_rc))` (any value other than 0 (or empty) is evaluated to true). @konmi

Comment: The '$' is not needed, nor used in the answer, in `exec_rc -eq 1`. @konmi

Comment: I did not know that, I thought `$` was not used only within ``((  ))``.

Comment: In any arithmetic environment, `let`, `var[a++]`, `(( ... ))`, `$((...))`, etc. @konmi

Comment: However, `-eq` only forces an arithmetic context in a `[[ ]]` conditional expression, not in a `[ ]` test. `[ exec_rc -eq 1 ]` will get you a "[: exec_rc: integer expression expected" error. (This is just one of the many limitations of the `[ ]` form.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson a `-eq` (or `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt` or `-ge`) forces an an arithmetic comparison. Inside a `[[` is used to mean "an arithmetic environment", inside `[` is used to mean "a decimal integer" comparison. Inside a `[` the content of the variable has to be a decimal integer (if it starts with a `0` it is not accepted as an octal number, and a `0x` is rejected with an error). And, yes, we must write `[ $a -eq 1 ]` to compare the **content** of the variable, not its name. So, both have an additional set of rules, not the same set, clearly. @GordonDavisson

Comment: Why put the example that spawns a subshell in front of the one that doesn't? A lot of people don't bother to read the prose in answers and just pattern off the code sample they see; it's thus helpful to put the code sample representing best practices first, and others after that.

Comment: BTW, `[ $a -eq 1 ]` is still problematic because it doesn't guarantee that `$a` will be parsed as a single argument. `[ "$a" -eq 1 ]` results in better error messages in cases where `a` expands to invalid content, and also can avoid undesired behavior in odd situations like `a='0 = 0 -o 2'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy About *Why put the example that spawns a subshell in front of the one that doesn't?* Because I wrote the answer adjusted to the OP question. The smaller change to his initial code is that first line, then, expanding on the idea, progressively better approaches.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy About *[ $a -eq 1 ] is still problematic* Yes! that is correct. That is one reason for why such code doesn't appear in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `[[ … ]]` throughout (a [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) construct). Note that inside conditional expressions, equality between integers is spelled `-eq` (`==` would do a text pattern matching, which may or may not work in your specific script depending on the values `exec_rc` can take).

```
if [[ $exec_rc -eq 1 && (-z $keymap_actm || -n $modmap_actm) ]]; then …
```

Note that you need space around the `[[ … ]]` delimiters (except next to command-separating punctuation such as `;`), but you don't need spaces around parentheses and operators inside the conditional expression.

Comment: I'd generally suggest having spaces around `(` and `)` even though they aren't strictly needed in this context, because they're need in _so many other_ shell contexts, using them when there's any doubt is the better habit to promote.